# NNJoin aborted with error "worker: no geometry"

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I have a series of points in a csv file, with lattitude, longitude  in WGS84, and I want to know to which country they belong. These points are on the shore, not inside a country, that's why I'm using NNJoin plugin to have the distance to the nearest country.

The shapefile for countries is the one provided by natural earth ( ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip downloaded here https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/).

When I run NNJoin, I get the error "worker: no geometry" and aborted error. It doesn't provide any more information in the log. It happens on QGIS 2.18 and 3.0

Any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the error ! latitude and longitude were empty in one line...